# Docker + MariaDB gives me ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: docker, mariadb, debian, dockerfile

I try to install and run MariaDB in a Debian container. Everything works until I want to run `mysql -u root`. Here is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl \
                       build-essential

RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-client
RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-server
RUN service mysql start
RUN mysql -u root
```

I get following error message: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant just run mysql process in build procedure. It should be done when you run container. Example:
Build:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl \
                       build-essential

RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-client
RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-server

ENTRYPOINT service mysql start && mysql -uroot
```

Then build image:

```
docker build -t my-mysql-image .
```

And finally you can run container and login into mysql shell:

```
docker run -ti --rm --name my-mysql-service my-mysql-image
```

By the way, there is official mariadb image on dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb which you can use instead of custom build.